# Existence of Pillai equations with Catalan type solutions?

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-geometry, elliptic-curves, diophantine-equations

In Catalan's conjecture we have $$x^m-y^n=1$$ having solution $(3,2,1,1)$ and $(3,2,2,3)$.

Call $$ax^m-by^n=k$$ to be Pillai Diophantine equation.

> 1. Is it true no Pillai Diophantine equation exists with integer solutions $(x,y,m,n)$ and $(x,y,m+1,n+r)$ with $1<r$ true at $a=b=1\neq k$?
> 2. Is it also true at any fixed $a,b\in\Bbb Z$ and at any fixed $k\in\Bbb Z$ with $abk\neq0$ or $|a-b|\neq |k|$?

Following Jeremy Rouse's post both are no. His answer also works $k>0$ for 2. if $a=-2$ and $b=-7$ which has $b<a$.

I suspect there is no further equations with $k>0$ and $a=b=1$ or $k>0$ with $b\geq a$. **I assume this to be true** (without proof).

However his solution has $(m+1,n+r)-(m,n)=(1,2)$ and the main query I seek is whether we can get $(m+1,n+r)-(m,n)\neq (1,2)$ and $gcd(m,n)=gcd(m+1,n+r)=1$ at:

> 3. $a=b=1$ and $k>0$?
> 4. any other $a,b$ with $a,b,k>0$?

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are constants.

Comment: You should add a top-level tag to your question, in this case nt.number-theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to questions 1 and 2 are both no. In the example you consider, where $m = 1$, $n=1$ and $r = 2$, you are seeking solutions to $x-y = x^{2} - y^{3} = k$. The equation $x-y = x^{2} - y^{3}$ is an elliptic curve and the largest integral point on this curve gives you a solution for $k = -20$, namely
$$
  -20 = (-14) - 6 = (-14)^2 - 6^3.
$$

Variants of this trick work for other values of $a$ and $b$. For example, if $a = 2$ and $b = 7$ we find that
$$ -86968 = 2 \cdot (-40754) - 7 \cdot 780 = 2 \cdot (-40754)^{2} - 7 \cdot 780^{3}. $$
Indeed, there are $9$ different values of $k$ that work for $a = 2$, $b = 7$, $m = 1$, $n = 1$ and $r = 2$.

EDIT: The answers to questions 3 and 4 are also both no.

For one thing, the "trivial solution" with $x = 1$ and $y = -1$ gives $k = 2$ whenever $n$ and $n+r$ are both odd. However, there are many non-trivial solutions too.

For example, if $m = n = 1$ and $r = 4$ with $a = b = 1$, we have solutions with $k = 4$ and $k = 13$, namely
$$ 4 = 6-2 = 6^{2} - 2^{5}, \quad 13 = 16 - 3 = 16^{2} - 3^{5}. $$
This shows the answer to question 3 is no.

If we take $a = 2$ and $b = 7$, with $m = n = 1$ and $r = 4$ we find
$$ 175 = 2 \cdot 105 - 7 \cdot 5 = 2 \cdot 105^{2} - 7 \cdot 5^{5}. $$
This shows the answer to question 4 is no too.

Comment: is the answer yes if $k>0$ at least if $a=b=1$?

Comment: If $a = b = m = n = 1$ and $r = 2$, the only solutions have $k \in \{ -20, -4, -1, 0, 1, 2, 9 \}$. For $k = 9$ we have $x = 15$, $y = 6$, for $k = 2$ we have $x = 1$, $y = -1$. By the way, this elliptic curve is not a Mordell curve.

Comment: $x^2-y^3=k$ looks similar to Mordell curve and you look at intersection with a line $x-y=k$ (correct?).

Comment: The equation of the elliptic curve is $x-y = x^{2} - y^{3}$. I have finding all of the integral points on this curve. Each of these lives on a line $x-y = k$, but I'm only finding $k$ after I find the points.

Comment: Thank you I have accepted. However do you think we need to start with $m=n=1$?

Comment: No. There are solutions $a = b = 1$ and $m = 2, n = 1, r = 2$. There are also solutions with $a = 2, b = 3$ and $m = n = 2$, $r = 2$, in particular with $k = 125$ (although you did say you were interested in cases where $\gcd(m,n) = 1$).

Comment: My curiosity arose from this https://oeis.org/A090129. the sequence has $1,2,2,4,8,16,32,\dots$. Why does the $2$ repeat and what is the right generalization? So far I have failed.